# Opengl ES 3.1+ support on iOS through Vulkan wrapper

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vulkan

Now that a [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) to [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) wrapper is officially supported by Khronos ([MoltenVK](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK)), and that OpenGL to Vulkan wrappers began to appear ([glo](https://github.com/g-truc/glo)), would it be technically possible to use OpenGL ES 3.1 or even 3.2 (so even with support to OpenGL compute shaders) on modern iOS versions/HW by chaining these two technologies? Has anybody tried this combination?

I'm not much interested in the performance drop (that would obviously be there due to the two additional layers of abstraction), but only on the enabling factor and cross-platform aspect of the solution.

Comment: Have you actually looked at GLO? It's not even a *thing* yet. It doesn't have texture or *shader* support. You cannot render with it. And considering that it was last updated a year ago, it's probably not getting better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, yes :).

MoltenVK doesn't support every bit of Vulkan (see the [Vulkan Portable Subset](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/portability-initiative) section), and some of those features might be required by OpenGL ES 3.1. Triangle fans are an obvious one, full texture swizzle is another. MoltenVK has focused on things that could translate directly; if the ES-on-Vulkan translator was willing to accept extra overhead, it could fake some or all of these features.

The core ANGLE team is working on both OpenGL ES 3.1 support and a Vulkan backend, [according to their README](https://github.com/google/angle/blob/master/README.md) and recent commits. They have a history of emulating features (like triangle fans) needed by ES that weren't available in D3D.